# What is mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Everyone, I am trying this

```py
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y)) # MSE
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

but I got an error

```
Variable rnn/output_projection_wrapper/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/Adam/ already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

Please suggest the solution

Comment: Have you trying searching online? https://medium.com/@hideyuki/what-does-variable-reuse-mean-in-tensorflow-40e86535026b

Answer (score 0):

Reuse means sharing the same variable between different objects.

If you would like to share a variable then you have to explicitly specify `reuse=True` in the varscope of the variable, or set the varscope to `reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE`.

You can use [tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/reset_default_graph) at beginning of your code, which clears the default graph and resets the global default graph.